# Find an open transaction across any session and any database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction

I know that we can use `select @@trancount` and `select * from sys.sysprocesses where open_tran = 1` to find if a session has an open transaction in a given database. The problem with these statements is I have to run them in the same window where the transaction was begun.

We have 10 different databases in our dev server. I want to know if there is a way to find out if a transaction is open in any of those databases across any session. I have a problem where I started a transaction to test something and closed the session without committing or rolling it back. I want to find out if the transaction is still open and if so how do I close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/docs/12_transaction/):

> In its default mode Who is Active shows any session with an active
> transaction. This state is reflected in the [open_tran_count] column,
> the value of which is the depth of nested transactions that have been
> started—implicitly or explicitly—on the request or session.

Once you have listed the undesired open session, you can kill it using the session ID:

```
KILL 87;
```

But you need admin privileges to do so.